# How to take action based on detection of locked or off screen in flutter app

Tags: flutter, background-process, flashlight, off-screen

By using a flutter package from **pub.dev** named **"torch_compat 1.0.2"** for turning on/off flashlight in android app, how to turn off flashlight **(trigger TorchCompat.turnOff())** when locked or off screen state detected.

**Current code:**

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:torch_compat/torch_compat.dart';

class FlashlightOnOffButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FlashlightOnOffButtonState createState() => _FlashlightOnOffButtonState();
}

class _FlashlightOnOffButtonState extends State<FlashlightOnOffButton> {
  bool isFlashlightOn = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data = MediaQuery.of(context);
    var isPortrait = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    return Container(
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          isFlashlightOn ? TorchCompat.turnOff() : TorchCompat.turnOn();
          setState(() {
            isFlashlightOn = !isFlashlightOn;
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.lightbulb,
          color: isFlashlightOn ? Colors.deepOrangeAccent : Colors.white10,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Maybe your are looking for these [package](https://pub.dev/packages/is_lock_screen) [package2](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_state)*

A more about [flutter App Lifecycle](https://medium.com/pharos-production/flutter-app-lifecycle-4b0ab4a4211a) may help you in achieving your desired results.

Comment: How to track user activity in app, i meant user clicking/navigating to app(in all screen) ? I want a global solution, not by implementing gestureDetection in every screen. Any idea on this ?